# How to set a common @Qualifier for all beans inside Spring's Configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I have `@Configuration` with all beans having the same qualifier (many objects of the identical types coexist within one container, their dependencies and the objects themselves are qualified)

```
@Configration
class ExampleConfiguration {
    @Bean @Qualifier("foo") Foo foo() { ... }
    @Bean @Qualifier("foo") Bar bar(@Qualifier("foo") Foo foo) { ... }
    @Bean @Qualifier("foo") Baz baz(@Qualifier("foo") Bar foo) { ... }
}
```

Is there a way to use a single qualifier for all beans and injections inside given configuration (i.e for the whole configuraion, without repeating the annotation several times)?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve with the qualifiers?

A qualifier is only needed when you have multiple beans of the same type to allow Spring to determine which one you want to inject. In your case foo, bar and baz all have different types

Comment: I have several `Foo`, several `Bar` and so on, all of them are qualified with @Qualifier("something").  I want to reduce number of `@Qulifier` annotation, and keep the configurations free of them

Comment: Going off [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24020) there is no way to set a qualifier at the configuration class level if that is what you mean